# xcode7 not showing simulator iOS 9.0 destination options

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode7

Installed the Xcode 7 beta.  Can't run any code because Xcode only seems to allow me to choose "iOS Device" destination and none of the sim devices I would normally expect.  The project is set to iOS 9.0 target and Universal.  And it's a basic, new project.

Here's what I tried:

1. Changing the target to iOS 8.0, then I see sim devices.  But I want to run iOS 9.0
2. Xcode Menu > Preferences > Downloads > only see iOS 8.3, 8.2 downloadable... don't see mention of iOS 9.0
3. Xcode Menu > Open Developer Tools.  See option for iOS Simulator and iOS Simulator (Watch).  If I open iOS Simulator (not the watch), it opens up iOS Simulator 9.0 but running a watch
4. So looks like the iOS 9 simulator is installed but only for the watch.  Odd.
5. Xcode Menu > Preferences > Locations > switched Command Line Tools to Xcode 7.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK found it... go to window > devices, hit "+" there and add an iOS 9.0 simulator.  Weird... don't remember ever having to do this before (the simulators for all the iOS version / physical device types) just were there automatically.

Comment: Did you happen to delete your ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator directory?  Xcode should create a set of devices by default.  I'd be curious to see your ~/Library/Logs/*.log if there are any errors reported there.

Answer (score 1):

if your project **deployment target** is set to above 9.0, then you won't be able to see the list of simulators. You need to change the Xcode project deployment target to 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

Found Solution,
Go to **~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator** and delete "**devices**" folder, And **restart** Xcode, Now you can see all simulators.